# Query from Parse.com if object not exist

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

This is my query code from parse:

```
func queryFromParse(){
        //var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        var query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        let text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        let username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        let time = oneobject.createdAt!
                        let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                        let imageURL = userImage.url // <- Bruker nå userImage.URL, henter ikke bildefilen med en gang

                        var OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time, image: imageURL!)

                        self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.collectionView.reloadData() }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get error in code:

```
let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know why, because one of the rows in parse does not contains image:
[image]

Any ideas? What can I do to not get crash if there is not image there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, try something likt this:

```
func queryFromParse(){
        var query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        let text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        let username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        let time = oneobject.createdAt!

                        if let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                            let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile

                            let imageURL = userImage.url // <- Bruker nå userImage.URL, henter ikke bildefilen med en gang

                            var OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time, image: imageURL!)

                            self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

optionally unwrap that object:

```
let imageFile = oneobject["imageFile"] as PFFile
imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    if let imageData = imageData {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But what happen if i have a list of 1000 images, and only 1 of them has no image? Then it will not show any images at all, or?

Comment: Hm, whats wrong here?: http://s16.postimg.org/ne1ciqm6d/Screen_Shot_2015_09_13_at_22_24_08.png

Comment: I am still getting that error tho: http://s27.postimg.org/nqjbtqtcz/Screen_Shot_2015_09_13_at_22_57_13.png

Comment: well u cant get url from image stored in parse database .. it doesnt make sense ...

Comment: Yes, because in cellForItemAtIndexPath, i use this: "cell.imageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: post.image)!, placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))"

Comment: just make local struct that contains all properties of parse object and store it somewhere and then u can call image attribute cell.imageView.image = object.image .. u dont need setimagewithurl property ...

Comment: I don´t know how i could do that?

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
if let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
            let imageURL = userImage.url
        }
```